# How to safely measure a 480VAC waveform with a DAQ?

Tags: voltage-divider, voltage-measurement

I have a [LabJack U6](https://labjack.com/products/u6) Data Acquisition unit and would like to measure 12 (4 sets of 3 phase) 480VAC lines simultaneously at 600 samples/second. This would be used to evaluate a 480VAC 3phase, generator and utility system that has intermittent brown-out and black-out issues.  The voltage transducers in the existing hardware are not responding fast enough to determine which system or load is causing the issue. I have looked at other [voltage transducers](http://assets.tequipment.net/assets/1/26/vtr-series_datasheet.pdf), but it seems they all average and have a relatively slow refresh rate (~250ms).

My initial thoughts on this would be to use a voltage divider of 100:1 to get the voltage lower, feed that to a linear optocoupler, then feed the isolated side of the optocoupler into the DAQ. Am I reinventing the wheel here?

I would prefer to find a manufactured device for this, but have had no luck. I'm a mechanical engineer so maybe I just don't know the correct vocabulary.

Comment: So long as you can make sure the voltage is the same on either side of the optocoupler, sure, it should work.  Are you that worried about a surge that you feel the optocoupler is necessary, though? Yes, a DAQ isn't the kind of equipment that you are just ok with burning up, but I am not sure I see the optocoupler as a necessary component, there.

Comment: How accurate do you need this to be? You probably can get 480V->24V control transformers fairly cheaply if you don't need impressive accuracy, and those take care of the isolation as well.

Comment: This is a serious undertaking to find cause and effect of power line fault. Since there are many causes and reactions that may cascade in micro/milli-seconds. How can you expect to find the problem without monitoring current and sampling at a synchronous rate much faster.  http://www.atecorp.com/products/astro-med/dash-32hf.aspx

Comment: Whichever solution you choose, you must use fuses on the three hot legs of each feed. For little current, these can be [quite small and still meet the 500v rating](https://www.rapidonline.com/eska-632-707-time-delay-ceramic-micro-fuse-6-3-x-32mm-100ma-500v-pack-of-10-54-5677).

Comment: "floating measurement", "isolated probe", "isolated amplifier" could be relevant search terms.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Thanks for answering the question I should have asked ;-) If I proceed with this I will sample at a much higher rate and have a look at the unit you recommended. I am realizing that looking at the waveform is not a standard troubleshooting approach like you mentioned. I considered current transducers, but their response is even slower. The system must stay online for the next 8 months, and the issue is presenting itself every week or so. All I can think to do is get more data.

Comment: CT's can span to > 50MHz or more, keep looking and think about Fault conditions like surge inbalance, step loads, line regulation, power surge, arcs etc and get a consultant. What industrial load types and what KVA, % capacity margin?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 A consultant sounds like the best plan yet ;-) Lots of variable frequency drives of different ages and line tied motors for loads. The steam turbine is old with a mechanical governor. Its probably 200kW just guessing. The equipment that line ties it is probably 10 years old; but implemented with 50 year old ideas. So many variables, lol. We do employ EEs but they have not troubleshot much beyond replacing some VFDs. I will learn more about the system and post a new question specific to the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Get plant maintenance to make up a system block diagram with all the control parameters for fault detection/protection, load balance. VFD's are supposed to be soft starters depending on ramp rates but line tied motors and generators can cause load inbalance instabilities.

Comment: I think true RMS and apparent Power is more important than just V or I.  Get 3 consultants pick 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an error amplifier similar to the ADuM3190.  Those provide isolation and decent feedback for current sense/line sense.

Use the device as a standard amplifier for your divider and feed the output into the A/D of your microprocessor (if available).  The sample rate will likely be limited by your AD/DAQ.

Comment: Looks like a great linear amp but only rated for 2500V. Considering the risk of flashover, from follow-on grid current, I would choose fused 10kV power resistors with surge protectors for 9kV and use low voltage low impedance shielded cables to DAQ with balanced lines and Diff Amps, and step down 480V to 0.48V

Comment: Transorbs are your friend. Not sure why you'd need so much isolation but my specialty is elsewhere. I use these for current sense and line voltage, no problem. I am assuming his DAQ floats with respect to the AC lines, so as long as he has an AC return path, I'd say he's OK. Your scheme concerns me a bit.  Even with your additional surge protection, the lack of isolation gives me chills.

Comment: Considering how many electronics and LED Lamps burn up in Florida from lightning transients, residential hydro meters only have arc gap protection to 6kV and home electronics only protected to 3kV or less. This is an industrial enviro with generators and large inductive machines which can trip open and cause large surge voltages. I am suggesting 1000:1 attenuation on all ports with hi-V R's

Comment: I am familiar.  I have experience with lightning protection on composite aircraft.  Generally isolation is your best bet on those systems.  Transorbs to keep CM voltages down when possible.  We should chat offline, you are my senior and I'd love to pick your brain.

Comment: Sure anytime tomorrow 2:15 here

Comment: Cool.  I'll see if I can figure this system out and ping you.